# replace multiline string with regex using python

Tags: python, regex

My code doesn't work, its output 's still the same

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, filename = argv
f = open(filename, "r")
str = f.read()
f.close()
str2 = re.sub("<start>.*</start>","aa",str,re.DOTALL | re.M)
print str2
```

Test file

```
<start><a>
</a><a></a><a></a></start>
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work. But you have not said what your code is supposed to do? Or how it is not working, what else are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As per Python docs fourth argument in `re.sub` is not regex flag but a count.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

This should work:

```
>>> print re.sub(r"<start>.*?</start>", "aa", str, 0, re.DOTALL)
aa
```

Or with compiling regex first:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"<start>.*?</start>", re.DOTALL)
>>> print re.sub(regex, "aa", str)
aa
```

Or even this should work:

```
>>> print re.sub(r"<start>[\s\S]*?</start>", "aa", str)
aa
```

btw avoid parsing HTML using regex as it can be error prone in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intended outcome is, but if you are trying to replace everything between `<start>` and `</start>` then the following would work:

```
text = """<start><a>
</a><a></a><a></a></start>"""

print re.sub(r'(\<start\>).*(\<\/start\>)', r"\1aa\2", text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.M)
```

This would give you:

```
<start>aa</start>
```

You should really escape the `<` and `>` characters in your regular expression. It is also better practice to use a `with` statement when dealing with files:

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, filename = argv

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

text2 = re.sub(r'(\<start\>).*(\<\/start\>)', r"\1aa\2", text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.M)
print text2
```

This will take care of closing your file automatically. Lastly it is best not to use a variable name of `str` as it shadows Python's `str()` builtin function.